# Is there a detailed list of how to get reputation on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work on Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow)

I see from google that one can get +15 for accepted answers and +2 for accepting answers but I couldn't find a page with all the details for each action. I would apreciate a link.

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow/7238#7238

Comment: "How does reputation work?" is not really a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @cletus The linked dupe shows where you can rep up, how votes work and where you can lose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a detailed list in [this FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow/7238#7238).

Answer (score -1):

Ask good questions, provide better answers.

Comment: I said a detailed list, I know that already.

Comment: Mate, thats as detailed as it needs to be.